# Regex - Ignore the white spaces

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regex:

```
Regex.Match(result, @"\bTop Rate\b.*?\s*\s*([\d,\.]+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

And then parse it into int

```
topRate = int.Parse(topRateMatch.Groups[1].Value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
```

Example)

```
Top Rate: 888,888
Output: 888888
```

I'm getting the int output just fine by using my current Regex.
However, I noticed that when there are whitespace(s) in between the numbers
forexample,

```
Top Rate: 8         88,888
```

I only get an 8. Is there a way to just ignore any whitespaces that may or may not exist in between the numbers/after Top Rate letter?

Exmaple)

```
Top Rate:                       8                      88,888
Expected output: 888888

Top Rate:                       8     88,888
Expected output: 888888

Top Rate: 8                      88,888
Expected output: 888888

Top Rate: 8 8 8,888
Expected output: 888888

Top Rate: 888,          8  88
Expected output: 888888
```

Comment: What does your middle block (with the `->`) mean? What are the rules for the input? Give us some examples of what should and shouldn't match (and why)

Comment: I'd use a naive solution of removing all white spaces first then applying regex for my sanity.

Comment: @Flydog57 it means nothing. I was just trying to explain 888,888 ->(equals) 888888

Comment: @MarkSouls hmmmm ok. I was trying to add \s* to make it work if it's possible.

Comment: @davis If you know where whitespaces will be than it's ok, but otherwise I suspect it will become quite complicated.

Comment: @MarkSouls That's the thing. I'm converting it from PDF files. So you know, I can't say the whitespaces will be "always" there

Comment: But I've already done so many lines. There were so many similar situations like this and I've resolved by using regex. So I'm positive. It's do-able.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you cannot skip or omit whitespaces when matching and capturing the numbers, you could only do it by extracting several matches after a given string. However, there is an easy two-step approach.

You may add `\s` to match any whitespace or `\p{Zs}` and `\t` to match any horizontal whitespace to the character class. I would recommend capturing the number with `\d` first and then use an optional non-capturing group with a digit pattern at the end to make sure the number captured starts and ends with a digit:

```cs
\bTop Rate\b.*?(\d(?:[\d,.\s]*\d)?)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/r3IFl9/1). Note that repeating `\s*\s*` makes little sense, `\s*` already matches zero or more whitespace chars, and even `\s*` is redundant due to `.*?` that matches any zero or more chars other than LF chars as few as possible. To make it match across lines, add the `RegexOptions.Singleline` option.

*Details*:

- `\bTop Rate\b` - a whole word `Top Rate`
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than a newline char as few as possible
- `(\d(?:[\d,.\s]*\d)?)` - Group 1:

  - `\d` - a digit
  - `(?:[\d,.\s]*\d)?`  - an optional non-capturing group matching zero or more digits, `,`, `.` or whitespaces and then a digit.

Next, when you get the match only keep digits.

```cs
var text = "Top Rate: 8                      88,888";
var result = Regex.Match(text, @"\bTop Rate\b.*?(\d(?:[\d,.\s]*\d)?)", RegexOptions.Singleline);
if (result.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine( new string(result.Groups[1].Value.Where(c => char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray()) );
}
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/dOS6H4). With multiple matching:

```cs
var text = "Top Rate: 8                      88,888 and Top Rate:                       8  \n   88,888";
var results = Regex.Matches(text, @"\bTop Rate\b.*?(\d(?:[\d,.\s]*\d)?)", RegexOptions.Singleline)
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(x => new string(x.Groups[1].Value.Where(c => char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray()));
foreach (var s in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine( s );
}
```

See [this C# demo](https://ideone.com/ONDqRQ).

Comment: You always kill all my regex questions! Thank you so much for your help. This definitely works. One more thing. I recently changed the format from int to decimal. So when it hits IsDigit part it just makes 2,500.00 to 250000. Can we make it like when the number has a dot (2,500.50) then just get it as 2500.50 and when it doesn't (888,888) then just 888888.00 ?

Comment: @davis Try [this C# demo](https://ideone.com/8RN597). I suspect it is fine to remove any chars other than digits and dots.

Comment: Works perfect,,, always appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```cs
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
                    
public class Program
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    string[] texts = {
      "This should Not match the Top Rate thing",
      " Top Rate    : 888,888 ",
      "Top    Rate   : 8 8 8 , 8 8 8 ",
    };
    Regex rxNonDigit = new Regex(@"\D+"); // matches 1 or more characters other than decimal digits.
    Regex rxTopRate = new Regex(@"
      ^           # match start of line, followed by
      \s*         # zero or more lead-in whitespace characters, followed by
      Top         # the literal 'Top', followed by
      \s+         # 1 or more whitespace characters,followed by
      Rate        # the literal 'Rate', followed by
      \s*         # zero or more whitespace characters, followed by
      :           # a literal colon ':', followed by
      \s*         # zero or more whitespace characters followed by
      (?<rate>    # an named (explicit) capture group, containing
        \d+       # - 1 or more decimal digits, followed by
        (         # - an unnamed group, containing
          (\s|,)+ #     - interstial whitespace or a comma, followed by
          \d+     #     - 1 or more decimal digits
        )*        #   the whole of which is repeated zero or more times
      )           # followed by
      \s*         # zero or more lead-out whitespace characters, followed by
      $           # end of line
    ", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace|RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture );

    foreach ( string text in texts )
    {
      Match m = rxTopRate.Match(text);
      if (!m.Success)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("No Match: '{0}'", text);
      }
      else
      {
        string rawValue = m.Groups["rate"].Value;
        string cleanedValue = rxNonDigit.Replace(rawValue, "");
        Decimal value = Decimal.Parse(cleanedValue);

        Console.WriteLine(@"Matched: '{0}' >>> '{1}' >>> '{2}' >>> {3}",
          text,
          rawValue,
          cleanedValue,
          value
        );
      }
    }

  }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I verified and found with a small change in Regex statement, you can achieve your goal.

First one:

[image]

Second one:

[image]

Comment: I would rather not to use foreach for this task, because I have like 30 lines more regex to extract the info, so it will be a disaster and take forever to extract line by line. And I'm already only using the if statement to get all the values just fine.